# json.decode throws FormatException on nested double quote in json - dart

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Below code snippet throws Format Exception in Flutter json decode, Any suggestion please?

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'dart:convert';

Future<String> readBooks() async {
  String jsonString = '{"description":"As part of the "You Don’t Know JS" series","quantity":55}';

  Map<String, dynamic> books = json.decode(jsonString);
  return jsonString;
}
```

Format Exception:

> 2018-10-23 20:40:30.680 18115-18142/addon.com.bookshop E/flutter:
>   [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled
>   exception:
>       FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 26)
>       {"name":"As part of the "You Don’t Know JS" series","Age":55}
>                                ^
>
> ```
> #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:1358:5)
> #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:919:48)
> #2      _parseJson (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:29:10)
> #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:540:36)
> #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:167:41)
> #5      _MyHomePageState.readBooks (file:///E:/Me/TimePass/flutter/book_shop/lib/main.dart:58:39)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> #6      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (file:///E:/Me/TimePass/flutter/book_shop/lib/main.dart:48:39)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> #7      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:503:14)
> #8      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:558:30)
> #9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
> #10     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
> #11     TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:175:7)
> #12     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
> #13     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
> #14     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
> #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:143:19)
> #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
> #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
> #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
> ```
>
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
>       #19     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
>   (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
>       #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
>       #21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:99:5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just invalid JSON.
The inner quotes need to be escaped as `\"` to make your JSON valid.