# FormatException on parsing JSON with dart:convert

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I am trying to parse [this JSON](https://mangadex.org/api/manga/153) obtained using mangadex api.

All I need is the chapters in english which can be obtained from parsing this JSON.
This JSON also has titles in other languages which somehow gives me

```
FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 482, character 24)
```

for something like

> "title":"No es \"Mike\", sino...",

in the JSON file. There are many places with the same problem.

The JSON looks ok to me and has escaped inner quotes as mentioned in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952717/json-decode-throws-formatexception-on-nested-double-quote-in-json-dart)

All I want is all the `chapter` objects with `"lang_code": "gb"`

EDIT:

Currently for debug purpose I am storing the complete JSON as string in a file using the following code. I can later get the JSON directly via `GET` method.

```
import 'dart:convert' as json;
import 'json_sample.dart'; //contains the JSON as string

void main(){

  try{
    var decode = json.jsonDecode(data);
    print(decode);
  }on FormatException catch(e){
    print('error ${e.toString()}');
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you parsing the data?

Comment: @diegoveloper I have added the code

Comment: Do you get the same result if you fetch the data using http?

Comment: I fetched the data and it works fine. Why does saving as string gives me error? How do I get only the english chapter list here?

Comment: you should read this : https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51